# Django: How do I use a composite key as USERNAME_FIELD for django.contrip.auth.models.AbstractUser?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a custom user model extending `django.contrip.auth.models.AbstractUser`. The code model is as follows:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    name = "user"

    ROLE_CHOICES = [
       # ...role choices
    ]

    email = models.EmailField()
    username = None
    role = models.CharField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default="CONSUMER", max_length=255)
    profile_picture = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
    EMAIL_FIELD = "email"
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "user"
        verbose_name_plural = "users"
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['email', 'role'], name='unique_email_per_role')
        ]
```

Now I am getting error on `USERNAME_FIELD` because username has to be unique, but for my use case I want to keep the email unique per role. I have seen in `django.contrib.auth.model.User` there is `is_staff` column to identify staff role but in that way I do not want to keep on adding columns for every role. how do I define username for my model then? So that I can login to the django admin panel.

Comment: That is not possible, since this is the field that is used in the session, etc. so a single one. It also is quite odd to do that? A person would then log in again as producer, if they are not a consumer? So in that case what you construct here is not a user model, but some user-role model, so then the user model contains only the email adres, and might have different roles.

Comment: That being said, Django already *has* roles, indeed: groups....

Answer (score 0):

> have seen in django.contrib.auth.model.User there is is_staff column to identify staff role but in that way I do not want to keep on adding columns for every role.

You don't have to. Django already has support for roles, in Django that is called [**`Group`s** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#groups), groups form a many-to-many relation with users, and you can add permissions to groups.

You thus can make a group for the customers, one for the shops, etc. A user can belong to multiple groups at the same time.

Although it is not impossible you need a custom user model, Django's user model should normally cover most needs anyway.